# Can't extract time from timestamp Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, time, timestamp

Hi im trying to extract time from a timestamp in Postgres

```
SELECT extract(time from '2000-01-01 01:12:00'::timestamp)
```

Result should be:
01:12:00

It looks like that time is not a valid argument for extract. Is that right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
s=# SELECT cast ('2000-01-01 01:12:00'::timestamp as time);
   time
----------
 01:12:00
(1 row)
```

doesn't extract - then, you might want to use `cast`.

and yes - 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

`time` is not a valid aprt

Answer (score 18):

```
select '2000-01-01 01:12:00'::timestamp::time
```